# Given a system of inequalities $Ax \leq b$, how can I derive the upper and lower bound on $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of inequalities $Ax \leq b$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are unknown, and the $a$'s and $b$'s are constants.

$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$

Here's my attempt at trying to isolate $x_1$ and $x_2$ in order to obtain upper and lower bounds on them:

Given

\begin{align*}a_{11} x_1 + a_{12}x_2 &\leq b_1 \\
a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2&\leq b_2 \end{align*}
Suppose $a_{11}$ and $a_{21} > 0,$ then
\begin{align*}
x_1 &\leq \frac{b_1 - a_{12}x_2}{a_{11}}\\
x_1 &\leq \frac{b_2 - a_{22}x_2}{a_{21}}
\end{align*}
Suppose $a_{11}$ and $a_{21} < 0,$ then
\begin{align*}
x_1 &\geq \frac{a_{12}x_2-b_1}{a_{11}}\\
x_1 &\geq \frac{a_{22}x_2-b_2}{a_{21}}
\end{align*}

The upper bound of $x_1$ is $min\left(\frac{b_1 - a_{12}x_2}{a_{11}}, \frac{b_2 - a_{22}x_2}{a_{21}} \right)$, and the lower bound of $x_1$ is $max\left(\frac{a_{12}x_2-b_1}{a_{11}}, \frac{a_{22}x_2-b_2}{a_{21}}\right)$.

Is the above correct? These lower and upper bounds for $x_1$ also depend on $x_2$, and likewise, the lower and upper bounds on $x_2$ will depend on $x_1$. It sounds like a catch-22 where if $x_1$ changes, then the bounds for $x_2$ changes, which in turn will change the bounds on $x_1$. Is there a way to characterize the bounds on $x_1$ so that they do not depend on $x_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Fourier–Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination), of which you are performing just the first step. The next step is concluding that if the lower bound on $x_1$ is not greater than the upper bound on $x_1$, you know that a feasible $x_1$ exists, and you no longer need to specify its value, leaving you with inequalities for just $x_2$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read up on this. Does this approach ensure that the bounds on $x_1$ will not depend on $x_2$, and vice versa?

Comment: @Adrian yes, that's the outcome